# How to unset chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have the following code in my Chrome extension to detect when windows are closed:

```
    closeListener = chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener(function(closed_window_id){
        // something
    }
```

How do I unset this such that the anonymous function does not fire? i.e. Something like:

```
   chrome.windows.onRemoved.removeListener(closeListener)
```

**ANSWER**

[Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4394729/stephan-genyk)/[wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom)s answer is correct. The function within the addListener cannot be anonymous and the removeListener syntax uses the function name (or a variable pointing to the function) to clear it.

Updated codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EgpNpz

Comment: chrome.* API with function callbacks is asynchronous and doesn't return anything immediately. Use the standard javascript technique: named [global] function. See [How to stop a chrome web listener](//stackoverflow.com/a/23001552)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking a look at your code, I see your problem. The function you put into the `addListener` is anonymous and needs to be set to a variable or become a named function.

```
function newListener() {
    alert();
}
//This will add the listener
chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener(newListener);
//This will remove it
chrome.windows.onRemoved.removeListener(newListener);
```

Comment: That would be the one, but it doesn't seem to have the affect I'm hoping for.

Comment: This code seems to trigger the alert, though I believe it shouldn't?

    chrome.windows.create({
        "url":"http://www.example.com/",
    }, function(created_window) {
        var window_id = created_window.id;

        closeListener = chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener(function(window_id){
            alert();
        });
        chrome.windows.onRemoved.removeListener(closeListener);
        chrome.windows.remove(window_id,function(){});
    });

Comment: Sorry for the terrible formatting...

`    chrome.windows.create({
        "url":"http://www.example.com/",
    }, function(created_window) {
        var window_id = created_window.id;

        closeListener = chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener(function(window_id){
            alert();
        });
        chrome.windows.onRemoved.removeListener(closeListener);
        chrome.windows.remove(window_id,function(){});
    });
`

Comment: I give up. See here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RGBoKW